# Stored procedure exits when I create a table and insert into

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem creating and inserting in a table.

When I execute my stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it works successfully but when I execute it from Visual Basic, it doesn't work and stops when it tries to insert data into the table I created.

Visual Basic doesn't show any error, because as I said in SQL Server Management Studio, it works successfully.

```
CREATE OR ALTER proc COLLISION( @ID_FUNCION INT,    @ID_PELI INT,   @ID_SALA INT,   @HORARIO VARCHAR (8),   @ERR VARCHAR (MAX) OUTPUT) 
AS
    BEGIN   

    SET @ERR=NULL

    DECLARE @FECHAI VARCHAR(15), @ENRANGO INT

    SET @ENRANGO=0

    SET @FECHAI = (SELECT FECHAINICIO FROM PELICULAS WHERE ID_PELI=@ID_PELI)

   IF 0 IN (SELECT ID_SALA =
        case
            WHEN  DATEDIFF(MONTH,(SELECT FECHAINICIO FROM PELICULAS WHERE PELICULAS.ID_PELI=FUNCIONES.ID_PELI),@FECHAI)=0
            THEN 0
            ELSE ID_SALA
        end

    FROM FUNCIONES WHERE ID_SALA=@ID_SALA AND ID_FUNCION!=@ID_FUNCION)
        SET @ENRANGO=1


    IF @ENRANGO=1
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @HORA_HORARIOPELI INT,@MINUT_HORARIOPELI INT 
            DECLARE @HORA_HORARIOPRY INT,@MINUT_HORARIOPRY INT 
            DECLARE @HORA_DURACIONPELI INT,@MINUT_DURACIONPELI INT
            DECLARE @HORASUM INT,@MINUT_SUM INT


            SET @HORA_HORARIOPELI = SUBSTRING(@HORARIO,1,2) SET @MINUT_HORARIOPELI= SUBSTRING(@HORARIO,4,2)

            DECLARE @CONT INT
            SET @CONT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FUNCIONES)


            DROP TABLE if exists FUNCIONESAUX

            CREATE TABLE FUNCIONESAUX (ID_FUNCION INT,ID_PELI INT,ID_SALA INT,HORARIO TIME)


            3) INSERT INTO FUNCIONESAUX (ID_FUNCION,ID_PELI,ID_SALA,HORARIO) SELECT ID_FUNCION,ID_PELI,ID_SALA,HORARIO FROM FUNCIONES WHERE ID_FUNCION!=@ID_FUNCION
            --SELECT * FROM FUNCIONES
            --SELECT * FROM FUNCIONESAUX


            DECLARE @COLISION INT = 0



            WHILE @CONT>0
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ID INT = (SELECT TOP(1) ID_FUNCION FROM FUNCIONESAUX)
                    DECLARE @SALA INT = (SELECT TOP(1) ID_SALA FROM FUNCIONESAUX)

                    IF @SALA=@ID_SALA
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @HORARIOAUX VARCHAR(8) = (SELECT TOP(1) HORARIO FROM FUNCIONESAUX)
                        SET @HORA_HORARIOPRY =  SUBSTRING(@HORARIOAUX,1,2) 
                        SET @MINUT_HORARIOPRY= SUBSTRING(@HORARIOAUX,4,2)
                        DECLARE @HORARIOPRYMAYOR INT = 0

                        IF @HORA_HORARIOPELI<@HORA_HORARIOPRY
                            SET @HORARIOPRYMAYOR = 1

                        ELSE IF @HORA_HORARIOPELI=@HORA_HORARIOPRY AND @MINUT_HORARIOPELI<=@MINUT_HORARIOPRY
                            SET @HORARIOPRYMAYOR = 1




                        IF @HORARIOPRYMAYOR=0
                            BEGIN
                                DECLARE @DURACIONAUX VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT DURACIONPELI FROM PELICULAS
                                            WHERE ID_PELI IN (SELECT TOP(1) ID_PELI FROM FUNCIONESAUX)) 

                                 SET @HORA_DURACIONPELI =  SUBSTRING(@DURACIONAUX,1,1) 
                                 SET @MINUT_DURACIONPELI= SUBSTRING(@DURACIONAUX,3,2)

                                SET @HORASUM = @HORA_HORARIOPRY+@HORA_DURACIONPELI
                                SET @MINUT_SUM = @MINUT_HORARIOPRY+@MINUT_DURACIONPELI

                                IF @HORASUM>=24
                                    SET @HORASUM-=24

                                IF @MINUT_SUM>=60
                                    BEGIN
                                        SET @HORASUM +=1
                                        SET @MINUT_SUM -= 60
                                    END

                                IF @HORASUM>@HORA_HORARIOPELI
                                    BEGIN

                                        SET @ERR = CONCAT('(+H) Hay una colision de horarios, verfique que la funcion ingresada se encuentre en un horario libre',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
                                        RETURN;
                                    END

                                ELSE IF  @HORASUM=@HORA_HORARIOPELI AND @MINUT_SUM>@MINUT_HORARIOPELI
                                    BEGIN

                                        SET @ERR = CONCAT
                                    ('(+M) Hay una colision de horarios, verfique que la funcion ingresada se encuentre en un horario libre',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
                                        RETURN;
                                    END
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN 

                                DECLARE @DURACIONACT VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT DURACIONPELI FROM PELICULAS
                                            WHERE ID_PELI = @ID_PELI) 

                                SET @HORA_DURACIONPELI =  SUBSTRING(@DURACIONACT,1,1) 
                                SET @MINUT_DURACIONPELI= SUBSTRING(@DURACIONACT,3,2)

                                SET @HORASUM = @HORA_HORARIOPELI+@HORA_DURACIONPELI
                                SET @MINUT_SUM = @MINUT_HORARIOPELI+@MINUT_DURACIONPELI

                                IF @HORASUM>=24
                                    SET @HORASUM-=24

                                IF @MINUT_SUM>=60
                                    BEGIN
                                        SET @HORASUM +=1
                                        SET @MINUT_SUM -= 60
                                    END

                                IF @HORASUM>@HORA_HORARIOPRY
                                    BEGIN

                                        SET @ERR = CONCAT
                                    ('(-H) Hay una colision de horarios, verfique que la funcion ingresada se encuentre en un horario libre',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
                                        RETURN;
                                    END

                                ELSE IF  @HORASUM=@HORA_HORARIOPRY AND @MINUT_SUM>@MINUT_HORARIOPRY
                                    BEGIN
                                        SET @ERR = CONCAT
                                    ('(-M) Hay una colision de horarios, verfique que la funcion ingresada se encuentre en un horario libre',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
                                        RETURN;
                                    END
                            END

                    END
                        DELETE FUNCIONESAUX WHERE ID_FUNCION=@ID
                        SET @CONT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FUNCIONESAUX)
                END

        END




    END
```

The step 3 is where the stored procedure is executed in Visual Basic,
after that, it exits from it

Visual Basic code:

```
Imports ADODB

Module Modulo

Public insert As Integer = 0
Public modify As Integer = 1
Public baja_temp As Integer = 2
Public baja_perm As Integer = 3
Public consuta As Integer = 4
Public ID_empleado As Integer
Public fragmentoPelis As Boolean

Public consulta As Recordset
Public consultaMAX As Recordset
Public ban As Parameter
Public bande As Parameter
Public comadno As Command
Public comand2 As Command
Public comandUser As Command
Public banUser As Parameter

Public conexion As Connection
Public conexionp As Connection
Public conexiont As Connection

Public nusuario As String
Public consql As String


Public Sub conectpelis()

    conexionp = New Connection
    With conexionp
        .Provider = "sqloledb"
        .ConnectionString = "INITIAL CATALOG=CINECALIDAD_PELICULAS;SERVER=DESKTOP-CCNBSJH\SQLEXPRESS;INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=TRUE;Trusted_Connection=True"

        Try
            .Open()
            .Execute("use cine_pel")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End With

End Sub

Public Sub conectatickets()

    conexiont = New Connection
    With conexiont
        .Provider = "sqloledb"
        .ConnectionString = "INITIAL CATALOG=CINECALIDAD_TICKETSFUNC; SERVER=DESKTOP-CCNBSJH\SQLEXPRESS;INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=TRUE"

        Try
            .Open()
            .Execute("use CINE_TICKETSFUNC")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End With

End Sub

Public Sub conectarProcediminetos(nameProc As String, outParameter As Integer, ParamArray values()() As String)

    ban = New Parameter
    comadno = New Command

    With comadno
        .CommandText = nameProc
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


        For index0 = 0 To values.GetUpperBound(0)



            .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter(index0, values(index0)(0),
            ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, values(index0)(1), values(index0)(2)))


        Next


        .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter(outParameter, DataTypeEnum.adVarChar,
            ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput, 500, ""))

        If fragmentoPelis Then
            .ActiveConnection = conexionp
        Else
            .ActiveConnection = conexiont
        End If

        Try
            .Execute()
            ban.Value = .Parameters(outParameter).Value
            If ban.Value Is Nothing Then
//If this condition is true then, all it worked successfully
                MsgBox("All correct")
            Else

                MsgBox(ban.Value)
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

        End Try




    End With

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: None of those are stored procedures. Show us the actual VB code you are running, and (if you do have an Procedure) the DDL of the Stored Procedure.

Comment: That's part of the stored procedure code, but it's ok, I'll put all.

Comment: Out of interest, why `DROP` and recreate the table each time? Why not start with a `TRUNCATE`, or could there be a reason the table doesn't exist (seems odd if that is the case).  Visual Basic won't chose to stop the execution of a stored procedure mid way though, VB has no control over it. I suspect you are getting an error, but are surpressing it in your VB code you've omited.

Comment: The drop is because I was using the table as an auxilar but I preferred to change it, it's not necesary as you said using TRUNCATE works but I'm still having the same problem.
That table is necessary because I make a query in it, and I'm deleting each time the first row (DELETE FUNCIONESAUX WHERE ID_FUNCION=@ID)

Comment: Let me put the visual basic code where I call the stored procedure.

Comment: With your new code, *"The step 3 is where the stored procedure is executed in Visual Basic, after that, it exits from it"* doesn't make any sense. But my point stands, if it's not working, and generating an error, then that'll be passed back to VB. A Procedure won't just "stop" in the middle; nor will that behaviour change depending on what application code it was that called it. YOu need to debug the VB and check the error. If there isn't an error, you need to debug the Procedure, as it isn't doing what you *think* it is.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that I execute the stored procedure (collision) in VB, and it works
but when the stored procedure is been executed and it's on step 3 (when it insert into funciones...) it stops
and I say that it stops because I asign to the variable @err any value and return

Comment: For example:
-------
set @err = 'Im here'
return
---------
And well,  when on Visual Basic I get the message in the condition "If ban.Value Is Nothing Then" it should return me the value 'Im here' but it's not like that, because what is returning is null, and I dont know why it's doing that

Comment: I'll try to use debugger, I hope it works, although I also think it can be a security problem.
Thank you guy!

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, try adding [`SET NOCOUNT ON;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) as the first statement in the proc. This will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` (rowcount) messages that can interfere with result set processing with `ADODB` unless the code processes all result sets. In VB.NET, you should use `SqlClient` as that will perform better and avoid this problem.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you very much!!  I did wha you said, about adding "SET NOCOUNT ON" and it worked successfully. You have helped me a lot, tnank you